# What is the best way to protect a PHP page?

Tags: php, authentication

I want to implement a login system on my website that redirects a user to login.php if they are not currently logged in. I am currently using this approach :

```
<?php 
start_session();

if (!isset(_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    header('location:login.php');
    exit();
}
$user_details = get_user_details_from_db(_SESSION['user_id']');
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<p><?php echo "Welcome $user_details['name']?> You are in a protected area</p>
</body>
</html>
```

or should I encapsulate the entire contents in an if then else, such as :

```
<?php 
start_session();

if (isset(_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    $user_details = get_user_details_from_db(_SESSION['user_id']'); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<p><?php echo "Welcome $user_details['name']?> You are in a protected area</p>
</body>
</html>
<?
}
else
{
    header('location:login.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

I've seen both methods being used in places, so wondering if there is any issue with the first method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine both methods. 1st for protecting whole pages and the 2nd one for for example protected buttons or links which are directed to protected pages.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do both methods. The only error you'll get in the first one, is you forgot a $ on line 9. If you really want to secure your site, you should check if you get user details for your ID you get from your session.

Comment: And line 4 `$_SESSION[]` :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefere the first method. If the session is not correct then redirect and end execution, else continue.
Additionaly you can check if user details is correct:

```
$user_details = get_user_details_from_db($_SESSION['user_id']);
if (!isset($user_details['name']) {
    // redirect..
    exit();
}
```